Understanding ということにさせて
I am not quite sure about the meaning of ということにさせて in this panel:

I think this usage of にする is similar to the one used in 無かった事にする. One thing I don't get is why させて is used instead of して.

The causative form of a verb is also used for expressing allowance:

言わせてください。
Let me say this.
行かせて。
Allow me to go.

So your sentence means "Let me say I don't know" or "Let me pretend I don't know". She is implying that she actually knows the reason.
